# how can i make some install command run before compile process?

Tags: c++, cmake

I will use install command in my CMakeLists like this:

```
install(DIRECTORY lib-mmm/src/infra/ DESTINATION /home/nick/infra FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

this is command to install some directory to some place.

I want this run before other compile process.

but i found when i define it as install, it will be called only when make install, which is after make process.

how can i make install directory command run before real compile process?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem, especially since you're trying to install header files.  What is your actual problem?

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Can't find headers of `infra`?

Comment: @StephenNewell before compile the project, i will to install some header files to some place, and the project source code are using this place's header, so, install this header must be called first, then the compile process. i think install() cant make my install headers work first, i want to know how can i do this

Comment: You may copy files and directories during configuration process using [file(COPY)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#copy) command.

Comment: @gordan.sikic the problem is: used the old infra, because the source code are using infra code, so, before complie other codes, i must install infra first.

Comment: @nick - Don't try to install the headers at first, make an interface library using `add_library`, then you can have whatever needs those headers link against the library.  That also lets you remove the hardcoded path you're trying to install into.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that's what i want, much thanks!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @StephenNewell thx, i think i should not use install for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik there is no way to do this by using the same project. The install target depends on the targets being build and any dependency of building on the install target would result in a circular dependency.

There are alternatives though:

1. Use [`file(COPY)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#copy)
2. Use `execute_process` to set up, build & install another cmake project during configuration. It can be problematic though to get cmake to use the same options for that build. This could also be refined by getting `add_custom_command` involved...

---

In your case though simply adding the correct include directory using `target_include_directories` will probably work better though.